# Redefining \ref such that it is \eqref when you use \ref{eq: ...} and then it is \cref else

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

Pretty much what the title says. I want to use only `\ref` in my latex document, but when I write `\ref{eq: ...}` I want the `\ref` to be typeset as `\eqref`, and when I use `\ref{sec: ...}` or `\ref{fig: ...}` or anything else, I want it to by typeset as `\cref`.

Comment: Will every label name have a `:`?  That would make parsing the name easier.

Comment: Yes they would :)

Comment: There would be a problem if \eqref or \cref use \ref internally.  You will almost certainly need a new name.

Comment: Why not `\cref` for everything and configure the equation type?

Comment: Rather than redefine `\ref`, would you be willing to redefine `\cref` to that it acts like `\eqref` if the object being cross-referenced is associated with a counter named `equation`?

Comment: Finally, you should really set up a MWE to test this facility, to save us the effort of making one for you.

Comment: Redefining `\cref` to act like `\eqref` (like Mico said) would work as well.

Comment: I would really strongly advise you not to to this, changing the semantics of such a core latex feature will mean that your documents will be hard to translate to other formats and fragments of your document can't be moved to normal latex documents and more generally, things will break.

Answer (score 6):

Rather than redefine a low-level command such as `\ref`, I would redefine `\cref` so that it doesn't output a label (typically, "equation" or "equations") when its argument is some item that's associated with the counter `equation`. All you'd need to do is to run the directive

```
\crefname{equation}{}{}
```

after loading the `cleveref` package. Optionally, if you happen to load the `hyperref` package as well and do *not* wish the parentheses that surround a cross-referenced equation number to be part of the hyperlink, you may also want to run the directive

```
\creflabelformat{equation}{\textup{(#2#1#3)}}
```

The default is `\creflabelformat{equation}{\textup{#2(#1)#3}}`. Note the difference in where the opening and closing parentheses are placed.

---

In the following MWE (minimum working example), the `hyperref` package is loaded with the option `nameinlink` and the `cleveref` package is loaded with the option `nameinlink` to highlight what is being produced by `\cref`. The text mode is deliberately set to *italics* to demonstrate that both `\eqref` and `\cref` will typeset cross-referenced equation numbers (and their associated parentheses) in upright, i.e., "Roman" mode. This is a standard typographic convention.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}              % for "\eqref" command
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref} % just for this example
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}
\crefname{equation}{}{}
\creflabelformat{equation}{\textup{(#2#1#3)}} % optional

\begin{document}
\section{First}\label{sec:first}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:pyth}a^2+b^2=c^2\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:triv}1+1=2\end{equation}
\begin{figure}\caption{A figure}\label{fig:test}\end{figure}

\section{Second}

\itshape % Just to verify that equation numbers will be typeset
         % in upright ("Roman") mode by both \eqref and \cref.

%% An example with "\eqref"
Cross-references to equations \eqref{eq:pyth} and \eqref{eq:triv}.

\noindent%% An example with "\cref"
Cross-references to equations \cref{eq:pyth,eq:triv,sec:first,fig:test}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend redefining the `\ref`-macro as packages like hyperref that modify that macro might rely on its definition.

How about defining a macro with a name which is not already in use, e.g., `\MyRefChooseCommand` which examines whether its argument has leading phrases 'eq:' or 'fig:' or 'sec:' or whatsoever and then applies the appropriate referencing-command on that argument?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begingroup
\makeatletter
\@firstofone{%
  \endgroup
  %%----------------------------------------------------------------------
  %% Paraphernalia:
  %%......................................................................
  \newcommand\UD@Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
  %%----------------------------------------------------------------------
  %% Check whether argument is empty:
  %%......................................................................
  %% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<argument which is to be checked>}%
  %%                   {<tokens to be delivered in case that argument
  %%                     which is to be checked is empty>}%
  %%                   {<tokens to be delivered in case that argument
  %%                     which is to be checked is not empty>}%
  \newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
    \romannumeral0\expandafter\@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
    \@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
    \@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
    \@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\expandafter\@firstoftwo{ }{}%
    \@secondoftwo}{\expandafter\expandafter\@firstoftwo{ }{}\@firstoftwo}%
  }%
  %%----------------------------------------------------------------------
  %% Check whether argument's leading tokens form a specific token-sequence:
  %%......................................................................
  %% \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{<token sequence>}%
  %%                           {<a single non space token> that does
  %%                             _not_ occur in <token sequence>>}%
  %%                           {<internal token-check-macro>}%
  %%                           {<argument which is to be checked>}%
  %%                           {<tokens to be delivered in case <argument
  %%                             which is to be checked> has <token sequence>
  %%                             as leading tokens>}%
  %%                           {<tokens to be delivered in case <argument
  %%                             which is to be checked> does not have
  %%                             <token sequence> as leading tokens>}%
  \newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens[4]{%
    \romannumeral0\UD@CheckWhetherNull{#4}%
    {\expandafter\expandafter\@firstoftwo{ }{}\@secondoftwo}%
    {\expandafter\@secondoftwo\string{#3#2#4#1}{}}%
  }%
  \newcommand\UD@@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens[1]{%
    \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\@firstoftwo{}#1}%
    {\UD@Exchange{\@firstoftwo}}{\UD@Exchange{\@secondoftwo}}%
    {\UD@Exchange{ }{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}\expandafter\expandafter
     \expandafter}\expandafter\@secondoftwo\expandafter{\string}%
  }% 
  %%----------------------------------------------------------------------
  %% \UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{<internal token-check-macro>}%
  %%                              {<token sequence>}%
  %% Defines <internal token-check-macro> to snap everything 
  %% until reaching <token sequence>-sequence and pass that to
  %% \UD@@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens.
  %%......................................................................
  \newcommand\UD@internaltokencheckdefiner[2]{%
    \newcommand#1{}\long\def#1##1#2{\UD@@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{##1}}%
  }%
  \UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{\@CheckEq}{eq:}%
  \UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{\@CheckSec}{sec:}%
  \UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{\@CheckFig}{fig:}%
  %%----------------------------------------------------------------------
  %% \MyRefChooseCommand{<label>}
  %% 
  %% Examines the <label>-argument.
  %% Yields \eqref{<label>} in case <label> begins with 'eq:'
  %% Yields \cref{<label>} in case <label> begins with 'sec:'
  %% Yields \cref{<label>} in case <label> begins with 'fig:'
  %% Yields \cref{<label>} in case <label> begins with 'something else.
  %%
  %% The branches for 'sec:' and 'fig:' are somewhat pointless.
  %% They are just there for exhibiting how forther forking
  %% can be implemented.
  %%......................................................................
  \newcommand\MyRefChooseCommand[1]{%
    \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{eq:}{.}{\@CheckEq}{#1}{%
      \eqref %<- name of label starts with 'eq:'
    }{%
      \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{sec:}{.}{\@CheckSec}{#1}{%
        \cref %<- name of label starts with 'sec:'
      }{%
        \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{fig:}{.}{\@CheckFig}{#1}{%
          \cref %<- name of label starts with 'fig:'
        }{%
          \cref %<- name of label starts with something else.
        }%
      }%
    }{#1}%
  }%
}%

\begin{document}

\section{A nice section}\label{sec:nice}

\begin{equation}
a^2+b^2=c^2\label{eq:1}
\end{equation}


Referencing via \verb|\ref|-command yields:

\verb|\ref{sec:nice}| \(\to\) \ref{sec:nice}

\verb|\ref{eq:1}| \(\to\) \ref{eq:1}


Referencing via \verb|\MyRefChooseCommand|-command yields:

\verb|\MyRefChooseCommand{sec:nice}| \(\to\) \MyRefChooseCommand{sec:nice}

\verb|\MyRefChooseCommand{eq:1}| \(\to\) \MyRefChooseCommand{eq:1}

\end{document}
```

[image: jpg-image of pdf-output when compiling the above example]